# Turtle Library in Python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am having a huge issue using the turtle library. I have to write my initials AR for an assignment. Can anyone help?

```py
import turtle

turtlescreen

turtle.pos(400,400)
turtle.forward()
```

Here is the code I am trying to use. I am trying to right my initial "AR" with it.

Comment: We’re going to need far more information than this.

Comment: No, embarrassing.
To right "AR" means that  you want to initial your arrow to right side of screen?

Answer (score 1):

You've managed to cram *three* errors into *four* lines of code.  First, you don't need this and it's an error:

```
turtlescreen
```

so toss it.  Second, the `pos()` function *returns* the current turtle postion, not *set* it.  So instead of:

```
 turtle.pos(400,400)
```

You want:

```
turtle.setpos(400, 400)
```

and finally, as @Jamie notes, you need to pass a distance (in pixels) to `forward()`.  So instead of:

```
 turtle.forward()
```

Something like he suggests:

```
turtle.forward(15)
```

Complete code:

```
import turtle

turtle.setpos(400, 400)
turtle.forward(15)

turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `turtle.forward()` requires an input variable in pixels. See the documentation for [turtle.forward](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#turtle.forward):

> Move the turtle forward by the specified *distance*, in the direction the turtle is headed.

Try changing:
`turtle.forward()`

to something like:
`turtle.forward(15)`

Answer (score -1):

There's a few mistakes I can see. Firstly, there is no command called turtlescreen so you can remove that. Next, instead of tom.pos try using tom.setpos(x, y) or tom.goto (x, y). Lastly, you should put a value in tom.forward (length). I also recommend going through the Python Turtle documentation, https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle